# Зачем ставить многоточие при добавлении элемента в список?

Tags: golang, список

Привет. У меня есть непонимание следующего факта. `k` дней назад я столкнулся с проблемой, которая состояла в том, что в список не получалось добавить элемент. Делал это я так:

```
myList = append(myList, []int{element})
```

Эта проблема решилась так:

```
myList = append(myList, []int{element}...)
```

Теперь, уважаемая публика, помогите пожалуйста разобраться: что же я такое наделал, добавив `...`

Comment: собственно, должен был идти список параметров, а ты передавал один параметр массив. По идее вот так тоже должно было сработать: `myList = append(myList, element)`. А `...` похоже аналог spread operator в js, и позволяет передавать массивы/коллекции как список параметров, а не как один парамтер

Comment: [Справка](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Функция `append`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) имеет следующую сигнатуру

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

В разделе справки по [типам функций](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types), есть следующее

> The final incoming parameter in a function signature may have a type prefixed with `...`. A function with such a parameter is called variadic and may be invoked with zero or more arguments for that parameter.

> Последний входной параметр в сигнатуре функции может иметь тип с префиксом `...`. Функция с таким параметром называется *variadic* и может быть вызвана с нулем или больше аргументов для этого параметра.

Таким образом корректным вызовом были бы следующие:

```
myList = append(myList, element1, element2, element3)
```

В вопросе же идет попытка передачи массива. Для этого случая в справке есть раздел [*передача аргументов в `...` параметр*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> If the final argument is assignable to a slice type []T, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a ...T parameter if the argument is followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.

> Если последний аргумент может быть присвоен []T, он может быть передан без изменений как значение параметра `...T`, если за этим аргументом будет идти `...`.

Что и происходит, при вызове

```
myList = append(myList, []int{element}...)
```